# REGEXP on thats why or that's why

Tags: mysql, regex

Attempting to do a select using REGEXP to get rows where column is either **thats why** OR **that's why**

```
select * from table_name where column REGEXP 'that\'?s why'
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is the smallest SQL that reproduces your symptoms?  For example, "column" is a reserved word, so I doubt your query is literally as presented at the moment.

In any case, it all Works For Me(tm):
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Thats why' AS col UNION SELECT 'That\'s why') d WHERE col REGEXP 'that\'?s why'` gives me two rows, as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you need a regexp here.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = 'Thats why' OR col = 'That\'s why'
```

Or, if you looking for containing values:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%Thats why%' OR col LIKE '%That\'s why%'
```

Comment: Agreed. Using regex is just over-engineering for this problem.

Comment: Thank you, however I have a test row in a column with the data: "that's why"  yet a select * from table_name where column like '%that\'s why%' shows no result.